# jquery ui sortable - current element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, target

I'm using jQuery UI sortable to build a dashboard userface.
I'm wondering how I can fetch the item I was sorting last?

What I want to do:
I'm using the update event to fire a function > showing a 
hint, that the new position has been saved. I want to attach
the DIV the moved element but therefore I have to know which
one it was. Any ideas?

thx
TC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the item you just dragged (and dropped - to trigger the `update`), jQuery gives it to you in the callback function.

```
update: function(event, ui) {
    var theElementYouDragged = ui.item;
}
```